# bloom-generate ROS2 cannot find packages

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, debian, ros

I have a ROS2 package and it is using `OpenCV 4.6.0`.
I can build the package with `colcon-build --symlink-install` and also test it using `colcon-test`. The correct opencv version is found, which is `4.6.0`. But when I create `.deb` packets using `bloom-generate rosdebian` it cannot find the `OpenCV 4.6.0` but references to `OpenCV 4.5.4`. This is a conflict between the versions so no `.deb` packaets are created. How do I make the `bloom-generate rosdebian` find the right version?

I do not understand why `build` and `test` can locate the right version mentioned in the CMakeLists.txt but not `bloom-generate`.